# Update password field from Titanium application

Tags: ios, titanium, cloud, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I'm working on a Titanium based iOS application.

In which I need to implement the password reset functionality within my app.

[image: Password reset]

I found this `requestResetPassword` method for doing this:

```
Cloud.Users.requestResetPassword({
    email: 'me@mycompany.com'
}, function (e) {
    if (e.success) {
        alert('Success: Reset Request Sent');
    } else {
        alert('Error:\\n' +
            ((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
    }
});
```

From docs it says that, it'll send a reset password option to user's mail account. But I don't want that. I need to reset password within my application.

Also I can't remove the current user and create a new account for the same user with new password because there is a lot of custom data saved for each particular user. So that's not a good solution.

Also I found the `update` function, but I don't know how to use it for updating the password field in cloud, because it is not a custom field.

```
Cloud.Users.update({
    email: 'me@mycompany.com',
    first_name: 'm',
    last_name: 'e',
}, function (e) {
    if (e.success) {
        var user = e.users[0];
        alert('Success:\\n' +
            'id: ' + user.id + '\\n' +
            'first name: ' + user.first_name + '\\n' +
            'last name: ' + user.last_name);
    } else {
        alert('Error:\\n' +
            ((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
    }
});
```

Is there anyway to do this from my application ? How can I update user's password field within my application ?

Referred docs:

1. [**Titanium.Cloud.Users-module**](http://tidevcn.com/apidoc/Titanium.Cloud.Users-module.html)
2. [**Titanium.Cloud.Users**](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Cloud.Users)

Please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "update". Specify the password properties like you do in your create call:

```
{
    password: 'cheese',
    password_confirmation: 'cheese',
    email: 'codfish@joe.com'
}
```

http://cloud.appcelerator.com/docs/api/v1/users/update

Comment: Thanks dude, can I ask one more question, how can I get the current password of current user ? I'm a new comer in Titanium, so please help me :)

Comment: You can't. Appcelerator can't. It's one way hashed.